# Will a professional PL s35 anamorphic lens cover a fuji sensor and provide proper squeeze?

Tags: lens-adapter, fujifilm, cinema, anamorphic

I have a fuji x-mount camera which is aps-c. As far as I understand it aps-c is just about the same size as super35, and I can buy a PL mount adapter for my fuji camera. Does this mean if i use something like an Atlas Orion 2x i would actually get a 2x squeeze? Or is there some other limiting factor I'm not understanding here. I can't seem to find videos or forums talking about using pro cine anamorphics on fuji, only those 1.3x sirui lenses made for fuji. Maybe I'm not even asking the right question.

Comment: Even if you succeed to mount the lens on the body you will get the same amount of pixels in the result file (but squeezed image). And if you try to extend it to get normal dimensions of the objects on the photo you should interpolate the pixels. Which will lead (IMHO) to not so high quality picture.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm sorry what? That's just how anamorphics work. I'm talking about using an anamorphic lens for video like normal.

Comment: I am sorry, i did not saw in your question to mention video. In such case will be better to ask your question here: https://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm also going to use it for photography. Regardless talking about interpolating the pixels has nothing to do with my question, that's a post-processing answer which i'm not asking about.

Comment: For photo you'll likely get better results by using a wide angle lens and cropping vertically.

Comment: Austin, I am trying to say you may reconsider using anamorphic lens because of the quality of final product

Comment: @xenoid - that will give a really different visual result, though; DoF, bokeh [& for video, focus or zoom pulls] will have a vastly different feel.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the sensor is covered depends on the size of the imaging circle. This is independent of whether an (optics-free) adapter is involved.  (Teleconverters and focal reducers change the size of the imaging circle.)

According to Wikipedia, the [Super 35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_35) frame size is  24.89mm × 18.66mm, which is larger than APS-C (approx 24mm × 16mm).  So a Super 35 lens should comfortably cover an APS-C sensor.

The squeeze factor of anamorphic lenses will be retained because it is applied optically before the light reaches the sensor.